# Set the height of a 'select' element in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, select, twitter-bootstrap, height, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I set the height of a `select` element in Bootstrap 3?

Here is my code:

```html
<select id="lst-size" name="p_size" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <option value="<?php echo "size1" ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo "{$rst_catalog['p_size1']}" ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo "size2" ?>"><?php echo "{$rst_catalog['p_size2']}" ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo "size3" ?>"><?php echo "{$rst_catalog['p_size3']}" ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo "size4" ?>"><?php echo "{$rst_catalog['p_size4']}" ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo "size5" ?>"><?php echo "{$rst_catalog['p_size5']}" ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo "size6" ?>"><?php echo "{$rst_catalog['p_size6']}" ?></option>
</select>
```

And the [live website](http://dohms.ru/pillow.php?p_id=2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to add the class `.form-control` to your `select` element:

```
<select id="lst-size" name="p_size" class="form-control col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
```

Answer (score 11):

Quite late, but with another flavor for those who freshly bump into this:

As of the time of posting this, and in the case of ***multiple select*** (*which to start with, is the query that even led me here*), the `size` attribute works nicely e.g `size="5"`. See sample below;

```
<select class="form-control" id="items" name="items" size="5" multiple>
    <option value="<?php echo "sizeX"> itemX </option>
</select>
```